# Как объединить разделы жесткого диска?

Tags: macos, mac, apple

Друзья,

в Disk Utility нет возможности удалить ненужный раздел жесткого диска, чтобы впоследствии объединить с основным. Что я делаю не так?

Скриншоты прикрепляю к посту:

[image: Кнопка удаления неактивна. Собственно, почему?]
[image: Этот самый раздел жесткого диска]

Дополнительно: 
Этот раздел ранее использовался как основной, под другую OS. Сейчас основным используется раздел Macintosh HD.